# Can you make Winston's jump work like Hanzo's?

Tags: overwatch

Is it possible to make it so you can hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to jump as Winston and then hit <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> again while in air to use your jump ability, like how Hanzo double jumps?

Comment: You can change it for all or for none. Though for all is pretty impractical unless you **only** play Winston

Comment: Why is this downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

No this sort of customization is not available for Winston's Jump Pack. It's unclear why you'd want it to be, aside from "put jumps on the jump button", so maybe you just need to think about it differently. After all, Hanzo's Lunge is the exception rather than the rule; pretty much all other characters' movement abilities are placed on the ability 1 button (default <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>).